# JOIN и LIMIT

Tags: yii, join, mysql

Здравствтуйте. Есть таблица компаний и таблица аккаунтов, в которой есть company_id. Аккаунтов может быть сколько угодно.
Требуется: выбрать 10 компаний и **все** аккаунты каждой из этих компаний.
Использую Yii. Если указать together=true, то вытаскивается почему-то 10-20 записей. Я примерно понимаю, что это из-за JOIN'а. Лимит срабатывает уже на объедненную таблицу.   
Пришлось выбрать 10 компаний, взять их id и аккаунты выбирать уже через WHERE company_id IN(...)
Может кто предложит решение получше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай связь м\у таблицами.

**Как пример:**

public function relations() {
'data' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Модель', 'Поле'),
}

а в поиске уже фильтруй

public function search()
{
}

Пример тут: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/database.arr

Answer (score 1):

```
$criteria->with = array('account'=>array('together'=>false));
```

Суть та же, единственное код не провоняет.

---

Попробуйте так:

```
$criteria->with = array('account'=>array('together'=>false, 'scopes'=>'scopeName', 'condition' => 'stringText'));
```

Comment: @dogmar, спасибо. Не знал, что together=false сделает запрос IN. Думал по запросу будет на каждую связанную запись.  
Только вот косяк. Как мне добавить условие для таблицы account, когда together=false? То есть, добавить условие когда будут выбираться связанные записи: WHERE IN(...) AND мои_условия. Можно как-то это сделать?